# Avoiding hard coding Schema in DB2/400 Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, db2-400, jt400

I'm creating Stored Procedures to replace Legacy app programs for an IBM i.  I'm calling the stored procedure from a Java Web App.  I'm using the jt400 JDBC driver

My JDBC URL is `jdbc:as400://myhost/;libraries=*LIBL,MYLIB;prompt=false`

The stored procedures can call stored procedures

The initial stored procedure call completes normally if it does not make further stored procedure calls

If the stored procedure makes a call to other stored procedures it fails with

```
com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCSQLSyntaxErrorException: [SQL0204] MY_SP in MYLIB type *N not found.
```

If I hard code a schema in the stored procedure call statement, the call completes normally.

I want to have the called stored procedures use the same schema as the caller

Answer (score 0):

You need to `SET PATH = "MYLIB"`

When I am using SQuirreL to call a stored procedure, I need to use the `SET PATH` statement to get it to find the stored procedure. I don't know if that is because my library list is bad or what, but the current schema is not used to find an unqualified stored procedure.

Comment: That does not seem much different from hard coding the Schema in the Call statement.  Isn't there a way in the JDBC URL to set the path?

Comment: Also, the initial stored procedure runs normally as long as it does not make additional calls

Comment: Are the stored procedures from the additional calls in the same library as the initial stored procedure?

Comment: Yes, same library

Answer (score 0):

I actually had this same problem, the stored procedure uses your job description library list. You need to edit that you can use `TAATOOL CHGLBLJOBD`. I am not in front of an iSeries at the moment but I believe the command was either `EDTJOBDLIB` or `EDTJOBDLIBL WRKJOBDLIBL`. It is some variation of that.